# Laravel not setting default cookies

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

When a page is loaded there aren't any cookies set in browser. I need csrf when a user logs in.
Within the form tag I set the token value with
`@csrf`.

I don't remember changing anything in Kernel.php but here it is:

```
namespace App\Http;

    use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

    class Kernel extends HttpKernel
    {
        /**
         * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
         *
         * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $middleware = [
            \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
            \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
            \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        ];

        /**
         * The application's route middleware groups.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $middlewareGroups = [
            'web' => [
                \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
                \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
                \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
                // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
                \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
                \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
                \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            ],

            'api' => [
                'throttle:60,1',
                'bindings',
            ],
        ];

        /**
         * The application's route middleware.
         *
         * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $routeMiddleware = [
            'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
            'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
            'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
            'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
            'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
            'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
            'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
            'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
            'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        ];

        /**
         * The priority-sorted list of middleware.
         *
         * This forces non-global middleware to always be in the given order.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $middlewarePriority = [
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        ];
    }
```

by default there should be an XSRF-TOKEN, and session cookie set by the framework right? What am I missing?

Laravel v6.4.0

Comment: the routes you are hitting all have the `web` group of middleware assigned?

Comment: did you surround your routes with web middleware ?

Comment: In routes I have `Route::get('/login', 'AdminController@login') -> middleware('web');` this is the page I'm hitting.

Comment: in what route file?

Comment: `routes/web.php`, not sure if `-> middleware('web')` necessary here but it wont work with or without.